# How to SELECT MAX(column) as max_value FROM my_table WHERE some_other_column = "something" in SQL

Tags: mysql

Below is my SQL table. I am trying to get the maximum value for `time`, where  `to_address` is `dfhuih`.

I have tried:

`SELECT MAX(time) as max_time FROM transactions WHERE to_address='dfhuih'`

However the result of that query gives the maximum `time` value in the table, irrespective of `to_address` - when using PHP mysqli.

**What is the correct way to select the maximum value in my `time` column where `to_address` is specified?**

```
transactions
 ---------------------------------------
| to_address |     time     |  amount  |
----------------------------------------
|  dfhuih    | 1536294884   |  0.320   |
|  dfhuih    | 1536343222   |  0.564   |
|  adslsd    | 1546294884   |  0.320   |
|  vshjfof   | 1536294884   |  0.320   |
----------------------------------------
```

The full code in my application is

```
$stmt1 = $db_connection->prepare("SELECT MAX(time) as max_time FROM transactions WHERE to_address=? AND from_address=? AND is_affiliate_payment=0");
$stmt1->bind_param('is', $user_id, $faucet_key);
$stmt1->execute();
$result1 =$stmt1->get_result();

while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
{
   echo $row['max_time']    
}
```

Comment: I think you've got the right idea, but there's something missing from your query, it should be: `SELECT MAX(time) as max_time FROM transactions WHERE to_address = 'dfhuih'`, note the addition of `FROM transactions`.

Comment: That works in phpmyadmin, but not when using PDO - when using PDO it gives me the max irrespective of to_address

Comment: Post the PDO code then!

Comment: @OscarChambers Show your PHP code then that constructs the query, likely something is missing that is omitting the WHERE clause.

Comment: I would regard that as 'impossible', you must be doing something wrong. PDO doesn't change your query, or the results.

Comment: In PDO a statement has `bindParam()` as a method, not `bind_param()`. What's going on?

Comment: I'm using bind_param everywhere else and it works fine

Comment: I have driven my car on the pavement elsewhere and I have never killed a pedestrian... in other words: That is not an answer.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php mysqli != PDO

Comment: i posted a answer which might help but for a better one i advice to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.. Then we all can stop making educated geusses

Comment: OK, it is not PDO, it is Mysqli, that explains it.

Comment: @WillemRenzema  I stand corrected, I am using mysqli - my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in these two line:

```
$stmt1 = $db_connection->prepare("SELECT MAX(time) as max_time 
                                  FROM transactions 
                                  WHERE to_address = ? AND 
                                        from_address = ? AND 
                                        is_affiliate_payment = 0");
$stmt1->bind_param('is', $user_id, $faucet_key);
```

There are two `?` in your query. The first is the `to_address`, the second is the `from_address`. Both are string. Yet in your `bind_param()` you ask for an integer `to_address`. So the code should be:

```
$stmt1 = $db_connection->prepare("SELECT MAX(time) as max_time 
                                  FROM transactions 
                                  WHERE to_address = ? AND 
                                        from_address = ? AND 
                                        is_affiliate_payment = 0");
$stmt1->bind_param('ss', $to_address, $from_address);
```

Note that I also changed the remaining parameters. Somehow `$user_id, $faucet_key` doesn't seem correct. Check that!

Answer (score 1):

i believe you are looking for, but hard to say for use without example data and expected results.

```
SELECT 
 transactions.*
FROM (
 SELECT 
   MAX(time) AS max_time
 FROM 
  transactions
 WHERE
   to_address = 'dfhuih'
) AS transactions_filter
INNER JOIN 
 transactions  
ON
   transactions_filter.max_time = transactions.time   
 AND  
   transactions.to_address = 'dfhuih'
```

Keep in mind it will also display ties if two MAX times values are the same

In MySQL 8 you can also rewrite that query into the query below. 
Notice the column alias moved as columnname to the derived table alias.

```
SELECT 
 transactions.*
FROM (
 SELECT 
   MAX(time)
 FROM 
  transactions
 WHERE
   to_address = 'dfhuih'
) AS transactions_filter(max_time) # <- here is the column alias also defined.
INNER JOIN 
 transactions  
ON
   transactions_filter.max_time = transactions.time   
 AND  
   transactions.to_address = 'dfhuih'
```

Comment: *"Would i add a LIMIT 1 somewhere to solve the tie? "* No @OscarChambers you would have to use MySQL's 8 `ROW_NUMBER()` or simulate it with MySQL user variables.. And filter on the rank.

Comment: Could you explain why such a complex query is needed?

Comment: *"Could you explain why such a complex query is needed? "* Yes i could but the topicstarter seams not to be needing the complete record data based on the max time value it seams.. The simple explainment would be you need to use a `JOIN` because you can't mix a aggregated column with non aggregate columns without using `GROUP BY`..  `SELECT MAX(time), amount as max_time FROM transactions WHERE to_address=? AND from_address=? AND is_affiliate_payment=0` for example would be a invalid SQL query.

Comment: mine statement *"because you can't mix a aggregated column with non aggregate columns without using GROUP BY"*  is also mentioned here in the MySQL's [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) documentation  @KIKOSoftware

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank your for the reaction. I see your point.